# Remove space from text and \rule

Tags: spacing, rules, cv, vertical

I'm writing a resume and I'm having trouble creating a certain appearance. [image]

I want to remove that space between education and the \rule. This is the code I currently have written

```
\textbf{EDUCATION}

\begin{center}

\rule{15cm}{.5mm}

\end{center}
```

I want it to appear as close as possible to this [image]

Thanks for the help

Comment: `center` is a display environment that adds vertical space, just remove that environment (and put `\noindent\rule...`

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}    
\begin{document}    

\noindent
\rlap{\rule[-1ex]{\linewidth}{.5mm}}EDUCATION

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd set the rule in a zero-width box, and then allow the text to just run over it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\newcommand{\sectionheading}[1]{%
  \noindent
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[-.2\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{.5mm}}%
  \textbf{#1}\par\nobreak
}

\begin{document}

\sectionheading{EDUCATION}

\lipsum[1]

\sectionheading{PUBLICATIONS}

\end{document}
```